# An equation invoking the Intermediate Value Property

Tags: real-analysis

I am thinking about the following problem:

> Let $f(x)$ be a function defined on $[0,1]$ with intermediate value property and such that $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$. Must there be some $c\in (0,1)$ such that $f(c)=c$? Note that $f(x)$ might not be continuous.

My guess is that the answer would be "NO". Here is my idea of constructing a counterexample. For any $\alpha \in (0,1)$, consider the fibre $f^{-1}(\alpha)$. Somehow we might require this fibre to be a countable dense subset of $(0,1)$. (Maybe by the axiom of choice?) So if we can work in this pattern "fibre-wisely", with each fibre $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ avoiding the point $(\alpha, \alpha)$, and thus obtain the desired counterexample.

Now questions: 1. Can such a construction be carried out? 2. If not, would there ever be such a counterexample?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note,  $f(x) would need to be non continuous, not just "might not" :). An obvious first place to look for ideas would be around Conway's base 13 function as the #1 go to for IVP functions that are weird.

Comment: Sure @Alan, if there is any counterexample that works, it should be a "bizzare" one :D

Comment: I think this will be true if $f$ had the property that it had one sided limits at each point. Unfortunately for a function with intermediate value property, jump discontinuity is forbidden.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93636/articles-with-examples-of-darboux-functions-without-fixed-points) seems relevant.

Comment: I have seen the counterexamples below, but why is it wrong to reason that $g(x) = x-f(x)$ has IVP, $g(0)=-1$, $g(1)=1$, and so $\exists c \in (0,1): g(c) = 0$ by the IVP?

Comment: See https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-28/issue-2/An-example-of-a-Darboux-function-having-no-fixed-points/rae/1184963801.full for a counterexample.

Comment: That's promising @Martin R. I also find this one useful.
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/missouri-journal-of-mathematical-sciences/volume-26/issue-2/The-Converse-of-the-Intermediate-Value-Theorem--From-Conway/10.35834/mjms/1418931955.full

Comment: @WhiteLake That's the very point of this problem. Sum of two continuous functions is still continuous. Yet the sum of two functions with intermediate value property may not retain the same property.